# Formtastic checkbox params sent differently by Capybara than by actual app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, formtastic

The following formtastic form checkbox field set:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @store do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :services, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Service.all %>  
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

is sending bad params for :services on a Cucumber test using Capybara, making the test fail, while the actual app sends the correct ones, which gets processed fine:

```
#cucumber steps using the boiler_plate capybara web_steps.rb:
Given a "Mail Order" service
...(steps for rest of the form)...
When I check "Mail Order" 
And I press "Create Store"
Then I should see "Store was successfully created."
And I should see "Mail Order"

#params sent by cucumber
"store"=>{"services"=>["[\"4d8247ed7f5bfd2275000004\"]"]

#params sent by app on manual test
"store"=>{"services"=>["4d8247ed7f5bfd2275000004"]}
```

Though the html form itself is rendered the same way in both cases:

```
<input id="store_services_4d8247ed7f5bfd2275000004" name="store[services][]" type="checkbox" value="4d8247ed7f5bfd2275000004" />
```

Seems like somewhere during the request params-building, the form key/value pairs for that field get parsed differently when submitted by Cucumber/Capybara.

Anyone else come across this?

Comment: That solution should probably be turned into an "answer" - other people may search for (and find) this problem, but skip over it, thinking there isn't a solution.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to answer my own question. Might not have enough privileges? I searched the meta site for answers about this, but no luck.

Comment: If you're logged in, you should have a big box just below these comments. Doesn't matter if it's your own question or not.

Comment: Well, I agree it shouldn't, but it seems to matter... no big box here :/

Comment: hmmm, actually it looks like I've got privileges now :) there's a big "Answer Your Question" link, which wasn't there at the time. Thanks for prodding, wouldn't have looked for it again otherwise.

Comment: Quite possible you only needed a few extra points and just one more upvote gave it to you. You should be fine from here on out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Got a pointer from Capybara's author, Jonas Nicklas, that led me to [this rack-test patch which hasn't been committed yet](https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/commit/7edd5bcb98a57686f015c26fc6c0c3dbdc3319d8)

For now I'm just using the fork and branch where the patch lives:

```
gem 'rack-test', :git => 'https://github.com/econsultancy/rack-test.git', :branch => 'econsultancy-20110119'
```

And that does the trick. I imagine this patch will be merged in very soon though, as it was submitted a couple of months ago.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I had figured that I could just update to a later version of rack-test with the fix as there are two more recent versions of rack-test. But the 3.0.x versions of Rails all depend on rack-test 0.5.7. So bundle complains that it can't update to any later version of rack-test for my rails 3.0 application.